# Is it okay to run the latest version of Ops Center (DSE 6.0) on the same instance as an app server...?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

Is it okay to run the latest version of Ops Center (DSE 6.0) on the same instance as an app server with 8GB mem and 2vCPUs for a dev server or is Ops Center better on its own instance?

We’ve seen that it requires good amount of resources.

Answer (score 0):

For development environment it could be ok, although this could lead to swapping, or slowness if you have quite a lot of data about cluster.

More general recommendation is to separate database tables used by OpsCenter from the your production tables - OpsCenter writes/reads quite a lot of data, and this could affect the performance. In production is always better to have a separate cluster for OpsCenter's data to separate load. Per DataStax license, instances in cluster used for OpsCenter doesn't require a separate license.